# Can't delete very large (1.2TB) files from Trash-computer freezes

Tags: delete, trash

I have three very large files .hdf5 (each 1.2TB) in my trash that I can't get rid of. Obviously I have tried simply emptying the trash. I have also tried deleting from Terminal with

```
 rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

I have also tried directly deleting the files from the .Trash-1000/files folder. All of these options have resulted in my computer freezing. The only thing I can do that works then is pressing. Once I restart, they are back in the Trash. Curiously I tried a 'move to' another folder which appears to move the files, but then my computer crashes and when I restart, they are back in the Trash.

```
alt-SySRq-REISUB
```

The only added information I can give is that I put these in the Trash by mistake and tried to restore them which crashed my computer.

Any help would be appreciated - I have been on this problem for 24 hours.

Comment: You can try to `split` the file into smaller files and the delete those, `split -b 20480 ~/.local/share/Trash/FILE_NAME`

Comment: Did it help to use `split`? Id like to know

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look on [the SMART status](https://askubuntu.com/a/528077/783023) of the disk, to make sure this is not the problem.

If that is fine, you can try and give the process *lower* IO, in order for it to not freeze the system

```
sudo ionice -c3 rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

EDIT:

I don't understand why this is downvoted here ? I checked and it is an acceptable answer on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/336917/is-there-a-way-to-delete-100gb-file-on-linux-without-thrashing-io-load/686049)

Answer (score -1):

Try *trash-cli* toolkit..
You can install it with *apt-get*.

> sudo apt-get install trash-cli

use *trash-empty* tool to remove trash, like:

> sudo trash-empty

best wishes